# Species differential abundance across time series samples

Tags: r, time-series, distributions, multivariate-analysis, ecology

Apologies if it is a stupid question or has been asked before or I have phrased it the wrong way, but I have been looking for an answer for days and I could not find anything - so any help will be greatly appreciated!

I am working with community ecology data and I have time series data showing the species abundance oven multiple time points (sampled once per year - no seasonality).

Example using R:

```r
library(factoextra)
set.seed(0)
dummy <- as.data.frame(round(matrix(rexp(200), 10)))
rownames(dummy) <- c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4", 
    "sample5", "sample6", "sample7", "sample8", "sample9", "sample10")
colnames(dummy) <- c("speciesA", "speciesB", "speciesC", "speciesD", 
    "speciesE", "speciesF", "speciesG", "speciesH", "speciesI", 
    "speciesJ", "speciesK", "speciesL", "speciesM", "speciesN", 
    "speciesO", "speciesP", "speciesQ", "speciesR", "speciesS", 
    "speciesT")
cats <- as.data.frame(rownames(dummy))
cats$year <- 2011
cats[2, 2] <- 2014
cats[3, 2] <- 2014
cats[4, 2] <- 2014
cats[5, 2] <- 2020
cats[6, 2] <- 2015
cats[7, 2] <- 2011
cats[8, 2] <- 2019
cats[9, 2] <- 2020
cats[10, 2] <- 2020
library(factoextra)
fviz_pca_biplot((prcomp(dummy)), pointsize=2, geom=c("point", "text"),
     habillage = cats$year, repel = TRUE)
```

As you can see, samples were collected in different years. What I would like to find out is whether samples of the same year or from nearby years (i.e. 2014 and 2015) have some unique species or some species more abundant than any other samples?  Suggesting that there may be distinct periods in time that the species distribution may have been influenced or that maybe the latest years some environmental or other factors may have created a selection pressure that favor certain species to emerge...

In the above example, in the prcomp plot you can see that samples collected in 2014 and 2015 seem to be influenced a lot by species B and species P.

If my predictor value was not time series but categorical (e.g. group A vs group B vs group C), I could simply perform some ordination or i could use a random forest for prediction or an indicspecies to find the most representative species in each group - but I do not know how to do this when I have time series data, and that is what I would like help with.

If any of you know any methods or packages in R (ideally) or some good tutorial or articles for reading, that would help A LOT!